# Find a model where an ID is in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb, sails.js

I use sails.js for Node.js + MongoDB and I'm trying to load all the groups in which my user is.
So I have a Group object with an array of ids (which are my users) like that

Group {
   users: array
}

What would be the fastest way to do it? Currently, I tried something like

```
db.Group.find( { users: { $in: [myUserId] } } )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `users` is an `array` you can do it simpler by:

```
db.Group.find( { users: myUserId } )
```

This will find any document where `myUserId` is in `users`.

Comment: Thank you so much ! I didn't know it was possible to do it in this way.